# How do i show this :for every prime $p> 3$ and every integer $k\geq1$ ,${p}^{4k}=1\mod3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences

There are many formula which are a multiple of $3$ for example $n^3+2n$ ,I accross this formula " ${p}^{4k}=1\mod3$" after some computations in WA then  **My question here is**:

How do i show this if it is true  :for every prime $p> 3$ and every integer $k\geq1$  then ${p}^{4k}=1\mod3$ ?

**Note:** I tried to use proof by induction but unfourtinately no General formula for primes known !!!
Thank you for any help

Comment: The fact that $p$ is prime isn't relevant, only that it's not divisible by $3$. Consider the remainder left when $p$ is divided by $3$, and take its fourth power.

Comment: Also $2k$ is sufficient, no need to use $4k$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Any prime $p>3$ is congruent to $\pm1\mod3$.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter that $p$ is prime.  Just that 3 doesn't divide $p$.

Let $p = 3q \pm 1$.  Then $p^m = (3q \pm 1)^m = $ via binomial theorem $ = 3^mq^m + ..... + 3q*(\pm 1)^{m-1} + (\pm 1)^m$.

So $p^m \equiv (\pm 1)^m \mod 3$.  If $m$ is even $p^m \equiv 1 \mod 3$.  The $4k$ and the requirement that $p$ be prime were overkill.